# How does this weird search pattern (destructuring) work in MongoDB promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ecmascript-6, promise

Following [this](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5399) issue in mongo, i've seen something that took my attention (look `then()` method)

```
// connect to mongo, use Mongo Client
mongoose.connect(MONGO_URI, {useMongoClient: true})
  .then(({db: {databaseName}}) => console.log(`Connected to ${databaseName}`))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

I did understand that in `mongoose` object there's a `db` attribute and two or three levels below there's a `databaseName` which is what I want in this case.

**My question(s)**:

- Is it ECMAScript2015 or some dark hack?
- What name does it have. No clue how to find it after a while trying

Thank you

Comment: [Object Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: if you don't understand the code, transpile it using [babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/) until the syntax becomes more apparent

Comment: __Tushar__ many thanks. That's the name I was looking for. __Jaromanda__ I did understand it but wanted to learn that new spell ;). This'll be my weekend project. Very powerful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking at is [ES6 destructing syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), not an object.

What it's saying is:

- take the argument passed to `.then()`
- find the `db` attribute on that object
- further destructure `db` to find the `databaseName` attribute within it
- hoist `databaseName` to the current scope (in this case, your function scope)

The deepest destructured variables will be available in the current scope. Here's an example:

```js
let { db: { databaseName } } = { db: { databaseName: 'ding' } }
// now databaseName is available in the current scope
console.log(databaseName)
// prints "ding"
```

This is the same syntax used for doing ES6 module imports:

```
// import the entire module into the current scope
import something from 'something'
// import only parts of the module into the current scope
import { InsideSomething } from 'something'
// some people also destructure after importing and entire module
const { InsideSomething, another: { InsideAnother } } = something;
```